# How to display an tree view inside notebook form view in odoo ?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a tree view inside an forme view in odoo 10,but the result is no table here is the result : 
[image]

and here is my model.py file an view.xml file :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, By checking your code I guess you need to interchange one2many and Many2one.
Tree view is not available for many2one

Comment: You cannot show a many2one field in a tree view but if you want to show more information in your view you can use related field to show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only display a list view with `x2many` fields. A `Many2one` field represents exactly zero or one record. There is no widget for showing such fields in a list.

If you want to show more data like name and unit price, you can override `name_get()` and build up another representation of such a record like `<name> (<unit_price>)`. You can use the context with some flags to only show this new name representation. The model `res.partner` is doing something like that. On normal views you can only see the partner name, but for example in orders you will also see the whole address. It's done by using the context flag `show_address`.

Another possibility is to write your own list widget for `Many2one` fields. But that would be a lot of work ;-)